# BluetoothGatt closing unexpectedly and app crashes, BluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on an application in Android Developer involving the connection to the a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) microcontroller to send a signal to the application and display it graphically. the microcontroller is the Nordic nRF51422 developer kit. I am able to connect to the Nordic device and receive the proper signal and have it be displayed in the application just fine. However, after about a minute or so of the application being run and displaying the signal, the app crashes. I looked into the Logcat and it mentions the following:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID)' on a null
>   object reference

I looked a little further into the Logcat and from what I can see it seems as if the BluetoothGatt is being closed on its own thus rendering the RX Service UUID null.

Here is the full Logcat:

```
06-25 16:16:10.273 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 1 line
06-25 16:16:10.273 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:10.274 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:10.274 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:10.711 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 286 lines
06-25 16:16:10.711 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:10.860 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:10.862 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 102 lines
06-25 16:16:10.862 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:11.059 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:11.268 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 202 lines
06-25 16:16:11.269 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:11.461 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:11.666 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 190 lines
06-25 16:16:11.666 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:11.862 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:12.693 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 498 lines
06-25 16:16:12.694 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:12.884 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.294 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 290 lines
06-25 16:16:13.294 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.465 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.469 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 102 lines
06-25 16:16:13.469 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.664 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.667 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/chatty: uid=10356(u0_a356) com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 identical 102 lines
06-25 16:16:13.667 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/GraphView: scrollToEnd works only with manual x axis bounds
06-25 16:16:13.864 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.869 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.870 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Disconnected from GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.871 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.872 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Connected to GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.872 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.873 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
06-25 16:16:13.876 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.880 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.881 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Disconnected from GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.885 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.886 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.887 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Connected to GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.887 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.887 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
06-25 16:16:13.889 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.890 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Disconnected from GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.895 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.899 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_DISCONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.901 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=8 device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.902 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Connected to GATT server.
06-25 16:16:13.903 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25
06-25 16:16:13.903 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 I/UartService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
06-25 16:16:13.904 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=DB:C3:A6:26:5D:25 Status=0
06-25 16:16:13.905 14856-15350/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/UartService: mBluetoothGatt = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@a0acd39
06-25 16:16:13.909 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 W/UartService: mBluetoothGatt closed
06-25 16:16:13.909 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/BluetoothGatt: close()
    unregisterApp() - mClientIf=8
06-25 16:16:13.913 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_CONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.923 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_DISCONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.934 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_CONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.943 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_DISCONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.955 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/nRFUART: UART_CONNECT_MSG
06-25 16:16:13.963 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-25 16:16:13.963 14856-14856/com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nordicsemi.fmECG_ver02, PID: 14856
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.getService(java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference
        at com.nordicsemi.nrfUARTv2.UartService.enableTXNotification(UartService.java:323)
        at com.nordicsemi.nrfUARTv2.MainActivity$5.onReceive(MainActivity.java:342)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

The code for the BLE connection I got from the Manufacturer here:

https://github.com/NordicPlayground/Android-nRF-UART

The null exception is happening in the function

> enableTXNotification()

when I attempt to call

> mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID)

Here is the code I use for the Bluetooth connection:

```
public class UartService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = UartService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.EXTRA_DATA";
    public final static String DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART";

    public static final UUID TX_POWER_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID TX_POWER_LEVEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a07-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID CCCD = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID FIRMWARE_REVISON_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID DIS_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID RX_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
    public static final UUID RX_CHAR_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
    public static final UUID TX_CHAR_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");


    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }


        //public String serviceUUID;

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                /*BluetoothGattService mBluetoothGattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
                if (mBluetoothGattService != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service characteristic UUID found: " + mBluetoothGattService.getUuid().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service characteristic not found for UUID: " + RX_SERVICE_UUID);
                }*/

                Log.w(TAG, "mBluetoothGatt = " + mBluetoothGatt );

                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

        // This is handling for the notification on TX Character of NUS service
        if (TX_CHAR_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

           // Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received TX: %d",characteristic.getValue() ));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, characteristic.getValue());
        } else {

        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        UartService getService() {
            return UartService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        Log.w(TAG, "UNBINDING");
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
     *
     * @param address The device address of the destination device.
     *
     * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
     *         is reported asynchronously through the
     *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     *         callback.
     */
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
       // mBluetoothGatt.close();
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.w(TAG, "mBluetoothGatt closed");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = null;
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    /**
     * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
     * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
     * callback.
     *
     * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
     */
    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
     *
     *
     */

    /**
     * Enable Notification on TX characteristic
     *
     * @return 
     */
    public void enableTXNotification()
    { 
        /*
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            showMessage("mBluetoothGatt null" + mBluetoothGatt);
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
            */
        BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
        if (RxService == null) {
            showMessage("Rx service not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID);
        if (TxChar == null) {
            showMessage("Tx charateristic not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

    }

    public void writeRXCharacteristic(byte[] value)
    {


        BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
        showMessage("mBluetoothGatt null"+ mBluetoothGatt);
        if (RxService == null) {
            showMessage("Rx service not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic RxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(RX_CHAR_UUID);
        if (RxChar == null) {
            showMessage("Rx charateristic not found!");
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
        RxChar.setValue(value);
        boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(RxChar);

        Log.d(TAG, "write TXchar - status=" + status);  
    }

    private void showMessage(String msg) {
        Log.e(TAG, msg);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
     * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
     *
     * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
     */
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }
}
```

I looked everywhere and could not find a solution so thanks in advance.